# Generate Enums from Tables using Telerik OpenAccess

Tags: telerik-open-access, openaccess

Reading the Telerik OpenAccess documentation, I see that I can set the data type of a Domain Class Property to an enumeration I have explicitly coded.  Instead of coding them, can I use OpenAccess to generate (and maintain) enumeration types from my tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enum generation based on a database table is not supported out of the box by the Telerik OpenAccess ORM but after a short search in Google I found [this Blog Post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html) demonstrating how to achieve that by a standalone code generation template.

You could also add a feature request in the [Ideas and Feedback portal](http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/114) of OpenAccess ORM for providing this functionality out of the box.

Comment: I had been experimenting with T4 initially (even had some success with the very code you linked to), then decided to experiment with a few "bigger picture" tools: ADO DataSets, the Entity Framework, Open Access ORM, and others, but in the end, T4 and XML seems to give me the flexibility to automate a DAL without sacrificing my coding style or architecture.  I think I'm going with T4.